# Zend Form add array of Elements in Display Group

Tags: zend-form

Here I've array of text boxes set belongs to one.

```
$this->addElement('text', '1', array(
        'label'   => 'Text One',
        'belongsTo' => 'txtarray'
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', '2', array(
        'label'   => 'Text Two',
        'belongsTo' => 'txtarray'
    ));

    $this->addElement('text', '3', array(
        'label'   => 'Text Three',
        'belongsTo' => 'txtarray'
    ));
```

I want to add these all to one display Group

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('txtarray'), 'pcinfo', array('legend' => 'Other Block'));
```

But this is not working.
How is that possible to add group of array Elements to display group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->addElement('text', '1', array(
    'label'   => 'Text One',
));

$this->addElement('text', '2', array(
    'label'   => 'Text Two',
));

$this->addElement('text', '3', array(
    'label'   => 'Text Three',
));
```

and then:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('1','2','3'), 'pcinfo', array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,'legend' => 'Other Block'));
```

And don't forget to add these lines:

```
$this->setDisplayGroupDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        'Fieldset'
    ));
```

You can visit this blog ,you will get great help
http://zendgeek.blogspot.in/2009/07/zend-form-display-groups-decorators.html